# gnuPlot: Plot data if certain condition is met

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot certain data from my data set that looks like:

```
29/11/2014;23:52;983,0;67,8;1016,0;53,0;53,0;29,7
29/11/2014;23:53;269,0;67,8;1018,0;53,0;53,0;29,7
29/11/2014;23:54;266,0;67,8;1008,0;53,0;53,0;29,7
29/11/2014;23:55;59,0;67,8;1011,0;53,0;53,0;29,7
29/11/2014;23:56;37,0;67,8;1016,0;53,0;53,0;29,7
29/11/2014;23:57;457,0;67,8;1000,0;51,9;53,0;29,6
29/11/2014;23:58;570,0;67,8;1000,0;53,0;53,0;29,6
29/11/2014;23:59;1140,0;67,8;1001,0;53,0;52,5;29,6
30/11/2014;00:00;1040,0;67,8;1005,0;52,5;53,0;29,6
30/11/2014;00:01;443,0;67,8;1000,0;53,0;53,0;29,6
30/11/2014;00:02;229,0;67,8;1008,0;52,5;53,0;29,6
30/11/2014;00:03;1035,0;67,8;1001,0;53,0;52,5;29,5
30/11/2014;00:04;681,0;67,8;1000,0;51,9;51,9;29,5
30/11/2014;00:05;931,0;67,8;1008,0;52,5;53,0;29,5
30/11/2014;00:06;889,0;67,8;1010,0;53,0;51,9;29,5
30/11/2014;00:07;885,0;67,8;1000,0;51,9;51,9;29,4
```

The field separator is the *semicolon* and the decimal separator is the *comma*, the fields *date* and *time* are considered independent to each other (They are separated by a *;* symbol)

This data set cover the whole month, but I only need to plot the data corresponding to *today*, for some reason, the plot command always ignore the data, so I suspect the command:

```
"plot file1 using (stringcolumn(1) == date1 ? $2:1/0):6 title " GPU" with lines, "
```

is malformed, but after reading a lot of net related articles, I cannot guess how.

The rest of the plot command in that line `" file1 using 2:7 title " CPU" with lines"` work as expected.

Comment: besides: instead of `1/0` you can write `NaN`, which is more readable

Comment: Thanks for your comment @krx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate an expression inside the `using` statement, you must use `timecolumn` in order to get the correct time data. Also, for string comparison use the `eq` operator:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M'
set datafile separator ';'
set decimalsign locale
date1='30/11/2014'

plot 'test.dat' using (strcol(1) == date1 ? timecolumn(2) : 1/0):6 with lines title "GPU"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, this solution worked right out the box.